# Revert to original image after jquery hover better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

to replace images on hover i have used jquery:

```
<script  type='text/javascript'>

            $(document).ready(function(){

                var blog1 = $(".blogimage1").attr('src');


                $(".imghover").hover(function() {
                    $(this).attr("src","images/imghover.png");
                        }, function() {
                    $(this).attr("src",blog1);
                });
            });

        </script>
```

here is the html:

```
<a href="blog-inner.html" title="read more">
                <img src="images/blogpost4.jpg" alt="blog post title" class="img-responsive imghover blogimage1">   
            </a>
```

and it works exactly like i want it to, however i dont know how many blog images there will be so for now i would have to add in blogimage1, blogImage2, etc into the html and do the same with jquery. is there a way i can do this without having to store each original blog image and write the same function a million times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : You can save previous image in `blog1` variable when mouse hover and replace it back when mouse leave.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var blog1 = '';

  $(".imghover").hover(function() {
       //save previous image in variable
       blog1  = $(this).attr('src');
       $(this).attr("src","images/imghover.png");
     }, function() {
          $(this).attr("src",blog1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store original image path.

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.

*code*

```
$(".imghover").hover(function() {
    $(this).data('orgimage', this.src); //Store data
    this.src = "images/imghover.png";
}, function() {
    this.src = $(this).data('orgimage'); //Retrieve and set original image path
});
```

Comment: @RMD2411, Yep using this you don't need to use a variable.